# UITableView Cell selected Color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection-color

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell`. The table view is showing data fine. What I am stuck in is when user touches cell of tableview, then I want to show the background color of the cell other than the default [blue color] values for highlighting the selection of cell.
I use this code but nothing happens:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 388, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, but according to the class definition for `selectedBackgroundView`:

> The default is nil for cells in plain-style tables (UITableViewStylePlain) and non-nil for section-group tables UITableViewStyleGrouped).

Therefore, if you're using a plain-style table, then you'll need to alloc-init a new `UIView` having your desired background colour and then assign it to `selectedBackgroundView`.

Alternatively, if all you wanted was a gray background when the cell is selected, you could use this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Comment: This property can also be set in the storyboard if you prefer to leave view related stuff to the view.

Comment: Swift 3 version : cell.selectionStyle = .gray // You can also use .none, .blue or .default

Comment: This answer is quite old... Has there somehing been changed in newer iOS versions?
I have a plain-style table and my selectedBackgroundView is NOT nil.
Interestingly changing the backgroundColor on this view does not have any effect, instead i have to replace it by a new UIView with my desired backgroundColor to make it work.

Comment: You just saved me from going completely insane. Many thanks!

Comment: you can just _change_ the backgroundView's backgroundColor property like so:
`cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = <your color`.

Answer (score 706):

No need for custom cells. If you only want to change the selected color of the cell, you can do this:

**Objective-C:**

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

**Swift:**

```
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

Comment: This works, but in a grouped UITableView, the rounded corners are lost.

Comment: @David Does the cornerRadius = 7 work anywhere in the grouped table view? What if the cell is in the middle? Don't have time to test this.

Comment: Why is masksToBounds necessary?

Comment: This is not working on OSX, saying : "NSView does not have a member named backgroundColor", anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: for swift is little mistake. Correct line is cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

Comment: Be aware that for this to work, in the Storyboard (or XIB file) you must select a Selected Background colour other than None. This is contrary to some answers that say you first need to set it to None for it to work. With None, it won't work. Was driving me crazy till I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: How would you make this work when you are also using storyboard?

Comment: @MaciejSwic Is there any way to reduce the size of selection color.When i select the whole cell is selcted i want only the text part selected

Comment: @Lyida What do you mean? You only want the background color of the text to change?

Comment: @MaciejSwic I have a customrized tableview cell.In left side i have a button  also.When i select cell it hide that button also.Is there  any way to reduce the size of the selection view.

Comment: @Lyida Sounds like a view hierarchy issue, are both your label and button inside the cells contentView? You may want to post a separate question for this.

Comment: @Lyida Please post a new question with screenshots and code, then link it here.

Comment: @MaciejSwic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502189/tableview-selection-hides-my-button-within-the-tableview-cell        Please take a look on it

Comment: Using this solution with `UIAppearance` did not work properly for **iOS 7.2**. Thats why I needed to put same solution in  `UITableViewCell` subclass and set the `backgroundColor` of the `selectedBackgroundView` in a custom `UIColor` property (with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`) - and that works like a charm. Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32208591/2471006) here.

Comment: Adding issue in other subview's background color.

Comment: You can create an extension using @IBInspectable to make this available in XIBs and Storyboards.

Comment: This works fine, but  why doesn't it work to set the `backgroundColor` of an existing (not nil) `selectedBackgroundView`???

Answer (score 52):

Table View Cell selection background color can be set via the Storyboard in Interface Builder:

[image: table view cell selection color None]

Comment: I think we cant set custom color from storyboard. Need to set it programatically.

Comment: If you have multi-select during editing this is no good solution..

Comment: And did you indeed find a good solution? I'm fighting exaclty this right now. I want no selection background/stripe color. When I go into multiselect editing mode, i want to be able to see the checkmarks get selected, but not a color. I am killing myself trying to figure out the dart through configuration that makes this work.

Answer (score 37):

If you have a grouped table with just one cell per section, just add this extra line to the code: 
`bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;`

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

**Don't forget to import QuartzCore.**

Answer (score 34):

Swift 3: for me it worked when you put it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.selectedBackgroundView = view
```

Comment: I think the better place to put this is `awakeFromNib()` method (in case of custom cell).

Answer (score 22):

The following works for me in iOS 8.

I have to set the selection style to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault` for custom background color to work. If any other style, the custom background color will be ignored. There seems to be a change in behaviours as previous answers needs to set style to none instead.

The full code for the cell as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // This is how you change the background color
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];        
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code is leaking memory. Any "alloc" or object creation must be in if (cell ==nil) { } block. Or the view will be created everytime the cell is released by iOS.

Answer (score 18):

Create a custom cell for your table cell and in the custom cell class.m put the code below, it will work fine. You need to place the desired color image in `selectionBackground` UIImage.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_bar.png"];
    UIImageView *iview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectionBackground];
    self.selectedBackgroundView=iview;
}
```

Comment: I think this could be more memory efficient than setting a selectedBackgroundView when initializing the cell by only creating the bg view when one cell is selected.

Answer (score 14):

#### Swift 3.0 extension

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var selectionColor: UIColor {
        set {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = newValue
            self.selectedBackgroundView = view
        }
        get {
            return self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

`cell.selectionColor = UIColor.FormaCar.blue`

Comment: add IBDesignable, and IBInspectable

Comment: @MichałZiobro just add `@IBInspectable` over the var if you want. `@IBDesignable` is not useful for this.

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 4, you can also set the background color of your table cell globally (taken from [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-change-uitableviewcell-selection-color-app-wide/)):

```
let backgroundColorView = UIView()
backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = backgroundColorView
```

Answer (score 9):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:view];
}
```

We need to set the selected background view in this method.

Answer (score 9):

#### Swift 4+:

Add following lines in your **table cell**

```
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor =  .red
self.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

Finally it should be as below

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor =  .red
        self.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add a custom highlighted color to your cell (and your cell contains buttons,labels, images,etc..) I followed the next steps:

For example if you want a selected yellow color:

1) Create a view that fits all the cell with 20% opacity (with yellow color) called for example backgroundselectedView

2) In the cell controller write this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     self.backgroundselectedView.alpha=1;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.backgroundselectedView.alpha=0;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.backgroundSelectedImage.alpha=0;
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a custom TableViewCell, you can also override `awakeFromNib`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Set background color
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    selectedBackgroundView = view
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks

Comment: I'm having a simple tableview with no more than 10 cells, this works great so far.

Answer (score 5):

I want to note that the XIB editor offers you the following standard options:

Section: blue/gray/none

(the right-hand column with options, 4th tab, first group "Table View Cell", 4th subgroup, the 1st of 3 items reads "Selection")

Probably what you want to do may be achieved by selecting the right standard option.

Comment: you're right. Due to, if you do so you can simple change the selection color in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" by adding: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255) green:(0/255) blue:(0/255) alpha:0.1];

Answer (score 5):

One more tip to Christian's way to show rounded corner background for grouped table.

If I use `cornerRadius = 10` for cell, it shows four corner's rounded selection background. It's not the same with table view's default UI.

So, I think about easy way to resolve it with **cornerRadius**.
As you can see from the below codes, check about cell's location (top, bottom, middle or topbottom) and add one more sub layers to hide top corner or bottom corner. This just shows exactly same look with default table view's selection background.

I tested this code with iPad `splitterview`. You can change patchLayer's frame position as you needed.

Please let me know if there is more easier way to achieve same result.

```
if (tableView.style == UITableViewStyleGrouped) 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        cellPosition = CellGroupPositionAtTop;
    }    
    else 
    {
        cellPosition = CellGroupPositionAtMiddle;
    }

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    if (indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1) 
    {
        if (cellPosition == CellGroupPositionAtTop) 
        {
            cellPosition = CellGroupPositionAtTopAndBottom;
        } 
        else 
        {
            cellPosition = CellGroupPositionAtBottom;
        }
    }

    if (cellPosition != CellGroupPositionAtMiddle) 
    {
        bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        CALayer *patchLayer;
        if (cellPosition == CellGroupPositionAtTop) 
        {
            patchLayer = [CALayer layer];
            patchLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 302, 35);
            patchLayer.backgroundColor = YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
            [bgColorView.layer addSublayer:patchLayer];
        } 
        else if (cellPosition == CellGroupPositionAtBottom) 
        {
            patchLayer = [CALayer layer];
            patchLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 302, 35);
            patchLayer.backgroundColor = YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
            [bgColorView.layer addSublayer:patchLayer];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per custom color for a selected cell in `UITableView`, great solution as per Maciej Swic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197802/3374975)

Just to add to that, you declare Swic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197802/3374975) in the Cell configuration usually under:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And for an added effect, instead of the system colors, you may use RGB values for a custom color look. In my code this is how I achieved it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

} 

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCustomCellName";
 MakanTableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCellClassName" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
                    } 

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/256.0 green:239.0/256.0 blue:49.0/256.0 alpha:1];
bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];


return cell;

}
```

Let me know if that works for you as well. You can mess with the `cornerRadius` number for the effects on the corners of the selected cell.

Answer (score 3):

To add the background for all cells (using Maciej's answer):

```
for (int section = 0; section < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
            NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];

            //stuff to do with each cell
            UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a slightly different approach than everyone else that reflects the selection on touch rather than after being selected.  I have a subclassed UITableViewCell.  All you have to do is set the background color in the touch events, which simulates selection on touch, and then set the background color in the setSelected function.  Setting the background color in the selSelected function allows for deselecting the cell.  Make sure to pass the touch event to the super, otherwise the cell won't actually act as if its selected.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.1)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.1) : UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To override `UITableViewCell`'s `setSelected` also works.

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Set background color
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    selectedBackgroundView = view
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for those that just want to get rid of the default selected grey background put this line of code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath func:

```
yourCell.selectionStyle = .None
```

Comment: thanks alot, this is the right answer for me not the others.

Comment: How to set a color like "green" instead of setting none or blue or grey.

Answer (score 2):

for Swift 3.0:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: Nice, but will work only after user select something (default selection color will remain at start)

Answer (score 2):

I use below approach and works fine for me,

```
class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

                var defaultStateColor:UIColor?
                var hitStateColor:UIColor?

                 override func awakeFromNib(){
                     super.awakeFromNib()
                     self.selectionStyle = .None
                 }

// if you are overriding init you should set selectionStyle = .None

                override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
                    if let hitColor = hitStateColor {
                        self.contentView.backgroundColor = hitColor
                    }
                }

                override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
                    if let defaultColor = defaultStateColor {
                        self.contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor
                    }
                }

                override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
                    if let defaultColor = defaultStateColor {
                        self.contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

1- Add a view to the content view of your cell.
2- Right click your cell.
3- Make the added view as "selectedBackgroundView".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the important parts of the code needed for a grouped table. When any of the cells in a section are selected the first row changes color. Without initially setting the cellselectionstyle to none there is an annonying double reload when the user clicks row0 where the cell changes to bgColorView then fades and reloads bgColorView again. Good Luck and let me know if there is a simpler way to do this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) 
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
        bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.85 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

        UIColor *backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1];
        cell.backgroundColor = backColor;
        UIColor *foreColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = foreColor;

        cell.textLabel.text = @"row0";
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == 1) 
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIColor *backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
        cell.backgroundColor = backColor;
        UIColor *foreColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = foreColor;

        cell.textLabel.text = @"row1";
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == 2) 
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIColor *backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
        cell.backgroundColor = backColor;
        UIColor *foreColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = foreColor;

        cell.textLabel.text = @"row2";
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[indexPath section]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tvStat cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}

#pragma mark Table view Gestures

-(IBAction)singleTapFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapRecog
{

    CGPoint tapLoc = [tapRecog locationInView:tvStat];
    NSIndexPath *tapPath = [tvStat indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLoc];

    NSIndexPath *seleRow = [tvStat indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if([seleRow section] != [tapPath section])
        [self tableView:tvStat didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:seleRow];
    else if (seleRow == nil )
        {}
    else if([seleRow section] == [tapPath section] || [seleRow length] != 0)
        return;

    if(!tapPath)
        [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [self tableView:tvStat didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tapPath];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Make sure you have used the above line to use the selection effect

Answer (score 1):

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Configure the view for the selected state

    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    let selView = UIView()

    selView.backgroundColor = UIColor( red: 5/255, green: 159/255, blue:223/255, alpha: 1.0 )
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selView
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your answer to make it readable for all future readers

Answer (score 1):

In case of custom cell class. Just override:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    if (selected) {
        [self setBackgroundColor: CELL_SELECTED_BG_COLOR];
        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor: CELL_SELECTED_BG_COLOR];
    }else{
        [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy when the table view style is plain, but in group style, it's a little trouble, I solve it by:

```
CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kGroupTableViewCellWidth+2, cellHeight)];
view.backgroundColor = kCommonHighlightedColor;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = view;
[view release];
UIRectCorner cornerFlag = 0;
CGSize radii = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
NSInteger theLastRow = --> (yourDataSourceArray.count - 1);
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cornerFlag = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
    radii = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
} else if (indexPath.row == theLastRow) {
    cornerFlag = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
    radii = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
}
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:cornerFlag cornerRadii:radii];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

noted the kGroupTableViewCellWidth, I define it as 300, it's the width of group table view cell width in iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iOS 9.3 and setting the color through the Storyboard or setting `cell.selectionStyle` didn't work for me, but the code below worked:

```
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55 / 255.0 
                                                  green:141 / 255.0 
                                                   blue:211 / 255.0 
                                                  alpha:1.0];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = customColorView;

return cell;
```

I found this solution [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style-color/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cellIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.backgroundView =
    [[UIImageView alloc] init] ;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] init];

    UIImage *rowBackground;
    UIImage *selectionBackground;


    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroundDarkGrey.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedMenu.png"];

    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
    ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;



    return cell;
}
```

//Swift Version:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell


        cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIImageView()
        cell.backgroundView=UIImageView()

        let selectedBackground : UIImageView = cell.selectedBackgroundView as! UIImageView
        selectedBackground.image = UIImage.init(named:"selected.png");

        let backGround : UIImageView = cell.backgroundView as! UIImageView
        backGround.image = UIImage.init(named:"defaultimage.png");

        return cell


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.x**

To Change the selection background Colour to anyColour use Swift **Extension**

Create UITableView Cell extension as below

```
extension UITableViewCell{

    func removeCellSelectionColour(){
        let clearView = UIView()
        clearView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = clearView
    } 

}
```

Then call **removeCellSelectionColour()** with cell instance.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5** - **Xcode version 12.1 (12A7403)**

**|Step One|**
Add the following to your **AppDelegate.swift** file

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let colorView = UIView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView
        
    return true
}
```

**|Step Two|**
Make sure your cell's Content View background is set to "Clear Color" (and not "Default") in the Attributes Inspector. This is done to not conflict with your App Delegate setting.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView reloadData];
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Use `[cell setClipsToBounds:YES];` for Grouped style cell