# UITableView deselect selected cells after editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I have multiple cells selected in a UITableView, but they automatically get deselected after editing. I searched a bit and I saw people saying that they called 'reloadData' which has caused the selections to be removed, but I do not call reloadData anywhere except for in 'viewDidAppear'. They get deselected even if the editing has been cancelled without changing anything (when clicking 'edit' button in the toolbar then clicking 'done' button without any editing). I'm not sure where this is happening. Or, if I could detect when the editing has been finished (when 'done' button has been clicked), I could simply reselect all the cells that had been selected, but I'm not sure how I could detect it..
How could I prevent the cells from getting deselected? Or reselect the cells after the edit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found out that `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` gets called whenever the 'edit' or the 'done' button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to achieve selection and deselection on Button press, If you are trying to change the state of selection in a UITableViewCell try using the method in the button action.

```
-(IBAction) someAction {
    if(buttonToggled){
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }else{
    //Do something
    }
}
```

for changing the backgroundColor.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

for more information on the above please check the link.

[UITableView Cell selected Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the best bet is just to reselect them yourself after every press on your "done" button.

It is quite normal that cells get deselected or buttons get unpressed, since this is their normal state - exept if you write your own code to change this - like in your case.

This is how to select a row:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

If you have multiple rows that can be selected make sure you have the settings accordingly, otherwise it might always deselect all but the most recent rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to select rows but then how could I detect when the 'done' button has been clicked?