# How to revert back the changes made in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` named as `Hobbies`.

Everything is working fine.Except one UIIssue.

When user taps on any `cell` I want to change the text colour of that particular `Cell` .And when user select another I want the previous selected `cell` should return to its original state.

Currently I am able to change the colour on `Cell` select but not able to revert it back when user selects another.

Here is the code I am using to change the `textColor` of a particular cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 HobbiesCell *cell = (HobbiesCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f];

}
```

How can I revert It back when user selects another cell.

Comment: try in this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545422/3134130

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object of UITableViewCell say `previousCell` and assign it each time you select one. This will be your last selected cell and you can assign it the default color each time you click a new cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HobbiesCell *cell = (HobbiesCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    previousCell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //Assuming that this is the color you want to go back 
    cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f];
    previousCell = cell;
}
```

Comment: I would discourage holding a reference to the cell itself as it is likely to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

You should always keep in mind that the cells are reusable, so the one you change will be used as is for displaying other rows when you scroll.

Instead, you should keep an array of your own models that keep the data (in your case color information) and use the cells only for displaying it.

To revert the color simply keep a reference to the latest `NSIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     MyRowModel *prevRowModel = [self.rowModels objectAtIndex:self.lastIndexPath.row];
     prevRowModel.color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:1f];

     MyRowModel *rowModel = [self.rowModels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     rowModel.color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f]; 

     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath, self.lastIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
     self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare this variable

```
int selectedIndex;
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
{
cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f];
}
else
{
    cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5f];//your default cell color
}
```

and in your didSelectRowAtIndex

```
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This assumes there is only one section the tableView

Answer (score 1):

If you go for reload the tableview then try this .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // reload the table 
  [tableView reloadData];
 HobbiesCell *cell = (HobbiesCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
previousCell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:0.5f]; // color insert which you want to insert 
}
```

hope it helps you without adding varible.

Answer (score 1):

Try **cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor**.

```
    if (cell == nil) {

        ........
         /* your cell initiation code */
        ........

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
```

Comment: I have write this method where ? Rashmi

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method!! Just try and check.

Comment: Yeah!! I'm an Indian.

Comment: Can we have a conversation :) @Rashmi

Comment: Either you create a chat room here or I :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92372/discussion-between-rashmi-ranjan-mallick-and-nsuser).

Answer (score -2):

You need to maintain a reference to the currently selected indexPath. Something like...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *currentHobby;
```

Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method insert this...

```
if(_currentHobby && ![_currentHobby isEqual:indexPath]) {
    HobbiesCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_currentHobby];
    currentCell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor originalColor];
}
_currentHobby = indexPath;
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` make sure you include...

```
if([indexPath isEqual:_currentHobby]) {
    cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor selectedColor];
} else { 
    cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor originalColor];
}
```