# Highlight Cell for Multiple selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to change the colour of my cell upon selection to a desired UI Color. Below is my code, and it is working fine. However, why the checkbox area is still in grey colour? How do I change that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 43.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 12.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I don't have enough reputations to post images. Sorry in advance!
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cphGq.png)

Comment: what kind of checkbox? And your cell is custom or kind from Apple?

Comment: @vienvu checkbox is from Xcode. Not custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpfull from my code snippet

```
var colorVw = UIView()
colorVw.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
cell.selectedBackgroundView = colorVw
```

Comment: for more info please find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color) . i also got the answer from this site.

Comment: thanks! it works. Deleted my `selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor` replaced with your `colorVw.backgroundColor`

Comment: I was doing so, but they needed me to wait for 1min. And you replied first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryView = nil
}
```